# Method Not Allowed (POST) in Django 3.0.7

Tags: python, django-3.0

I'm new to Django. I 'm trying to practice create Raw Update Class Based View but it get in to error Method Not Allowed (POST). Can any one help me please.

I already follow the instruction step by step but the result is the same. I also try a lot of method to fix but still can't. I really want to know what is the problem. I very appreciate for someone help me fix this.

view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.views import View
from .models import Client
from .forms import ClientFrom

class ClientUpdateView(View):
    template_name = "clients/client-update.html"
    def get_object(self):
        id = self.kwargs.get('id')
        obj = None
        if id is not None:
            obj = get_object_or_404(Client, id=id)
        return obj

    def get(self, request, id=None, *args, **kwargs):
        #GET Method
        context = {}
        obj = self.get_object()
        if obj is not None:
            form = ClientFrom(instance=obj)
            context['object'] = obj
            context['form'] = form
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)

    def post(self, request, id=None, *args, **kwargs):
        #POST Method
        context = {}
        obj = self.get_object()
        if obj is not None:
            form = ClientFrom(request.POST, instance=obj)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
            context['object'] = obj
            context['form'] = form
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

from .models import Client

class ClientFrom(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = [
            'Name',
            'Address',
            'Contact',
        ]
```

form in client-update.html

```
{% extends 'clienthead.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Update: {{object.id}} - {{ object.Name }}</h1>

<form action='.' method='POST'> {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type='submit' value='Save' />
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import (
    ClientUpdateView,
)

app_name = 'client'
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:id>/adjust', ClientUpdateView.as_view(), name='client-adjust'),
]
```